# How to find whether component of a vector can be greater than its own magnitude or not?

Tags: vectors

The component of a vector is : 
1. Always less than its magnitude.
2. Always greater than its magnitude
3. Always equal to its magnitude
4. None of these.

I know the answer will be 4. I can understand very easily that the component of vector can be less than its magnitude for example in a right angles triangle the hypotenuse is longer than both sides or we can say componnet of A along a line will be A.cos(theta) which must be less than or equal to A. Hence it is also possible to have component equal to A when cos equals 1. But is it possible to have component of vector greater than itself? If we think of component as A.cos(theta) then it is not possible according to range of cosine function but if we consider it geometrically we can construct a parallelogram whose diagonal is shorter than its length of sides when angle between vectors is obtuse and large or we can also construct a triangle with third side shorter than either. Is it possible or is only less than or equal to the only possibilities. May someone help?

Comment: As I know components of a vector are orthogonal to each other, so vector is the diagonal of the whateverdimensional rectangle and is greater or equal to it's components. You can't have components that are not orthogonal cos then they affect each other.

Comment: Do you know the formula for magnitude?

Comment: So what if they affect each other they are still the resolution of the vector.

Comment: Yes I know, it is basically cosine rule.

Comment: If your basis vectors are not orthogonal, it can happen.  e.g. suppose $v_1 = (1,0), v_2 (-1,1)$ are the basis vectors of your space, then $\|v_1 + v_2\|  < \|v_2\|$

Comment: @Doug Can you please elaborate what are basis vectors?

Comment: The subject is a little deep to cover in this space.  In the "standard basis" your basis vectors are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, frequently written as $\hat i, \hat j $.  They define your coordinate system.  But you are not obligated to use the standard basis.  You can choose a basis that transforms the coordinate system (to something built on parallelograms rather than squares or rectangles).  The rest of the rules of linear algebra still hold together despite the transformed basis.  It turns out to be a powerful tool.

Comment: If they are not orthogonal than it's not a resolution, it's just an addition of two vectors. Meaning of resolving is that components don't affect each other...

Comment: The question is only asking components of vector resolution word is nowhere mentioned.

Comment: I believe it's what they meant, words components and resolving are collocation